# Unable to register a DLL built on v4.6 on windows 10 system

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to register a **DLL (RegAsm)** that is build on a v4.6 framework in windows 10 however I keep getting an error stating

> Error RA0000: Failed to load "XXX.DLL" because it is not a valid .NET
>   assembly.

I was able to register the same DLL on this very system about a year ago on windows 10 OS itself.

The only change I could see is now windows 10 has v4.7.3 framework.

Can any one help me get this issue fixed?

Comment: Did you rebuild dll with Net 4.7.3?

Comment: I can't as I only have the DLL there is no source code for that DLL.

Comment: The dll will only work with same version of Net that it was built with unless you have the setup.exe folder to install.